# What is name of architecture component that handles the interaction with a remote service?

Tags: architecture, webservice-client

The old terminology from MSDN was a service agent. It would handle all the communication with services to supply the client app with data it needed. It would handle data transformation or other idiosyncrasies that the service required as well as retrying, etc.

I can't find any new literature discussing what the name of this component is now and would like some info and links to such resources.

Thanks!

Comment: I would call it as a Proxy or Service Proxy.

Comment: Thats what I currently have it as but was hoping for some kind of documented name.